# Validation in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.6

This question already asked but that is not solving my issue.

I have try to use validation in my `laravel project`. But it not working this is my code

```
$rules = array(
    'coupon_title'          => 'max:10',
    'coupon_type_id'        => 'numaric',
    'expiry_start_date'     => 'required|before_or_equal:expiry_end_date',
    'expiry_end_date'       => 'required',
);

$messages = [
    'before_or_equal'    => 'The :attribute must be smaller than the End Date',
    'before'    => 'The :attribute must be Greater than the Interview Start Date',
    'after'    => 'The :attribute must be Greater than the Interview End Date',
    'after_or_equal'    => 'The :attribute must be Greater than the Start Time',
    //'max' => 'asdasd'
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) 
{
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return response()->json(['message'=>$messages],401);
}
```

> In my code only `expiry_start_date` field validated.  But `coupon_title` and `coupon_type_id` fields not validated.

Comment: You have a tiny typo near coupon_type_id : it is 'numeric', not 'numaric' ;)

Comment: Are coupon_title and coupon_type_id allowed to be null?

Comment: @Virginia:Yes  #coupon_title allowed null values

Comment: Can you add the HTML part / the view where you are using these four variables (coupon_title, coupon_type_id, expiry_start_date, expiry_end_date? I think that might make it easier to spot the problem.

Comment: @Virginia: I set  `coupon_title` Null yes see this image https://imgur.com/a/QLtZIW2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct spell `numaric` to `numeric` and add `nullable` keyword in validation rule

```
'coupon_title'          => 'string|max:10|nullable',
'coupon_type_id'        => 'numeric',
```

Also you can add custom message for `numeric` and `max`

```
$messages = [
    'before_or_equal'    => 'The :attribute must be smaller than the End Date',
    'before'    => 'The :attribute must be Greater than the Interview Start Date',
    'after'    => 'The :attribute must be Greater than the Interview End Date',
    'after_or_equal'    => 'The :attribute must be Greater than the Start Time',
    'max' => 'The :attribute has crossed the limit',
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must have numeric value'
];
```

Comment: Working but i have doubt want to fields change null to yes in database ?

Comment: @RameshS Yes you need to make column nullable in mysql